# Timezone in Casablanca not valid

Tags: python, django, timezone, pytz

I'm using the pytz library (django timezone) to handle timezones on my website, and I noticed a wrong offset only for Africa/Casablanca, here is the example:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: import pytz

In [3]: from django.utils.dateformat import format

In [4]: paris = pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris")

In [5]: paris.localize(datetime.datetime.now(), is_dst=True)
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 25, 11, 25, 9, 473706, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)

In [6]: casablanca = pytz.timezone("Africa/Casablanca")

In [7]: casablanca.localize(datetime.datetime.now(), is_dst=True)
Out[7]: datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 25, 11, 25, 23, 416349, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Africa/Casablanca' WET0:00:00 STD>)

In [8]: format(casablanca.localize(datetime.datetime.now(), is_dst=True), "O") == "+0100"
Out[8]: False
```

Notice that Morocco is on DST since the April 1st.

Since we have a large number of visitors from Morocco it's a very frustrating issue.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

(OS: Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: File a bug report with the `pytz` maintainer?

Comment: I added an assert on the example above to be more explicit. I don't know what you mean by "bug report with the pytz maintainer". thanks

Comment: If `pytz` has the wrong information regarding DST for Casablanca, you should [report it as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pytz).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have an old version of pytz.  I ran your code using the latest version and it  shows the correct values.

Morocco changed it's DST rules for 2014.  Details [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/morocco/casablanca) and [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/morocco-ends-dst-2013.html).

This was put into [version 2013g of the time zone database](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2013-October/000015.html).  See the [Latest Versions](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#latest-versions) section of the pytz docs for updating information.

In general, if you are serving a global audience, you should monitor the [pytz atom feed](http://feeds.launchpad.net/pytz/announcements.atom), or the [IANA announcements mailing list](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), and plan on updating several times per year.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the atom feed. And you're right, my version wasn't up to date.

Comment: No problem - glad to help!  Please also remember to close the issue you raised on launchpad.  Thanks.